# how to run a openmp program on clusters with multiple nodes?

Tags: cluster-computing, openmp

I am using openmp to run a simple program.
And I have nodes on a clusters.A node have 16  threads.When I run a program as follow:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
double test()
{
    double a = 0;
    double s=0;
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        a=a+i;
        s=s+sqrt(a);
    }
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    double ss=0;
    double t1,t2;
    t1 = omp_get_wtime();   
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
            ss=ss+test();
    }   
    t2 = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout<<"time :"<<(t2-t1)<<std::endl;

}
```

using g++ on Red Had 4.1.2

cmakelists.txt:

```
PROJECT(VSHELLO)
SET(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp")
SET(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp")
SET(OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp")
MESSAGE("OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS: ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(vshello_OMP main.cpp)
```

When I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ,the total time is 14s
When I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=2, the total time is 7.2s

```
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./exe_omp
time : 14.3099
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./exe_omp
time : 7.20322
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./exe_omp
time : 3.64557
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./exe_omp
time : 1.92503
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 ./exe_omp
time : 1.206
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=32 ./exe_omp
time : 1.15374
..
#OMP_NUM_THREADS=128 ./exe_omp
time : 1.07625
```

Why the total time cannot decline when the threads number is more than 16?

Comment: OpenMP is a shared memory parallel programming paradigm. You cannot use it to program on a distributed memory system (or as you describe it: on a cluster of nodes). You'll have to combine MPI and OpenMP to take full advantage of your system.